# Synopse SQLite select rows for 1:N relationship

Tags: delphi, sqlite, table-relationships

I'm playing with the Synopse's SQLite implementation, but I'm stucked with the following piece of code. In the form constructor I create a database model where there are two tables `Task` and `Comment` and one table `TaskComments` with relationship 1:N for task comments. I can add the rows into the `TaskComments` table (Button1.OnClick event add one task and two comments for it) but I don't know how to get comments for this task back.

Can anyone suggest me how to get the N rows for a certain row (how to get comments for the task, in this case) ?

```
unit SynopseSQLiteTestUnit;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, SynCommons, SQLite3, SQLite3Commons, StdCtrls;

type
  TTask = class(TSQLRecord)
  private
    FTaskName: RawUTF8;
    FTaskCreated: TDateTime;
  published
    property TaskName: RawUTF8 read FTaskName write FTaskName;
    property TaskCreated: TDateTime read FTaskCreated write FTaskCreated;
  end;

  TComment = class(TSQLRecord)
  private
    FCommentText: RawUTF8;
    FCommentCreated: TDateTime;
  published
    property CommentText: RawUTF8 read FCommentText write FCommentText;
    property CommentCreated: TDateTime read FCommentCreated write FCommentCreated;
  end;

  TTaskComments = class(TSQLRecordMany)
  private
    FTask: TTask;
    FComment: TComment;
  published
    property Task: TTask read FTask;
    property Comment: TComment read FComment;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    Memo3: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FDatabase: TSQLRestClientURI;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  SQLModel: TSQLModel;
begin
  SQLModel := TSQLModel.Create([
    TTask,
    TComment,
    TTaskComments
  ]);
  FDatabase := TSQLRestClientDB.Create(SQLModel, SQLModel, ChangeFileExt(Application.ExeName,'.db3'), TSQLRestServerDB);
  TSQLRestClientDB(FDatabase).Server.CreateMissingTables(0);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Task: TTask;
  TaskID: Integer;
  Comment: TComment;
  CommentID: Integer;
  TaskComments: TTaskComments;
begin
  Task := TTask.Create;
  Comment := TComment.Create;
  TaskComments := TTaskComments.Create;

  try
    Task.TaskName := StringToUTF8('Task Name');
    Task.TaskCreated := Now;
    TaskID := FDatabase.Add(Task, True);

    Comment.CommentText := StringToUTF8('Comment Text 1');
    Comment.CommentCreated := Now;
    CommentID := FDatabase.Add(Comment, True);

    TaskComments.ManyAdd(FDatabase, TaskID, CommentID);

    Comment.CommentText := StringToUTF8('Comment Text 2');
    Comment.CommentCreated := Now;
    CommentID := FDatabase.Add(Comment, True);

    TaskComments.ManyAdd(FDatabase, TaskID, CommentID, True);

  finally
    FreeAndNil(Task);
    FreeAndNil(Comment);
    FreeAndNil(TaskComments);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Task: TTask;
  Comment: TComment;
  TaskComments: TTaskComments;
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  Memo2.Clear;
  Memo3.Clear;

  // here I want to select task with ID = 1, that's fine
  Task := TTask.CreateAndFillPrepare(FDatabase, 'ID = 1');
  // here I want to select all comments, that's fine
  Comment := TComment.CreateAndFillPrepare(FDatabase, '');
  // here I want to create the task comments, ok
  TaskComments := TTaskComments.Create;

  try
    // here I'm filling the memo boxes with the task and all comments, ok
    while Task.FillOne do
      Memo1.Lines.Add(UTF8ToWideString(Task.TaskName));
    while Comment.FillOne do
      Memo2.Lines.Add(UTF8ToWideString(Comment.CommentText));

    // here I'm trying to get all comments for task with ID = 1
    // but the FillOne function returns always False, what means, that
    // I don't get any row fetched
    TaskComments.FillMany(FDatabase, 1);
    while TaskComments.FillOne do
      Memo3.Lines.Add(UTF8ToWideString(TaskComments.Task.TaskName) + '; ' + UTF8ToWideString(TaskComments.Comment.CommentText));

  finally
    FreeAndNil(Task);
    FreeAndNil(Comment);
    FreeAndNil(TaskComments);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Many thanks

Comment: @mjn - If this tag would exist :-) But this is the minor of what I'm worried about.

Comment: Use the Synopse forum wich is very efficient.

Comment: OK, I'll try, but I've seen here Arnaud some time ago, so I was hoping he might help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should have posted this on the official mORMot forum, which is not sleeping like other marmots these days... but it's very nice seeing such a question in SO!

First of all, some general notes:

- You should better use `UTF8ToString` instead of `UTF8ToWideString` function;
- If you create your objects instances, you'd better use nested `try..finally` blocks: e.g. if the `TComment.CreateAndPrepare` constructor fails and raise an exception, you will never reach the `FreeAndNil(Task)` code, so you'll leak memory;
- Take care, using `FreeAndNil()` is very dangerous those days in the Delphi community - you may be anathemized!
- The main `FSQLModel` should be made public, and live during all database time;
- The `TSQLRestClientDB` 3d parameter (server model) should be nil;
- A `FormDestroy` is needed to release the memory, but it is not the main point here;

About your code, in fact, as stated by the documentation, a `TSQLRecordMany` sub-class **shall** have at least two published properties, named `Source` and `Dest`, by convention:

> - by default, only two TSQLRecord (i.e. INTEGER) fields must be created,
>   named "Source" and "Dest", the first pointing to the source record (the one
>   with a TSQLRecordMany published property) and the second to the destination record
>   ...
> - in all cases, at leat two 'Source' and 'Dest' published properties must
>   be declared as TSQLRecord children in any TSQLRecordMany descendant
>   because they will always be needed for the 'many to many' relationship

Then, it should work as expected:

```
  TTaskComments = class(TSQLRecordMany)
  private
    FSource: TTask;
    FDest: TComment;
  published
    property Source: TTask read FSource;
    property Dest: TComment read FDest;
  end;
```

And note that the `FillMany()` method only fills the `Source` and `Dest` as IDs, so you can't here directly get `Source.TaskName` or `Dest.CommentText`. You'll have to use instead e.g. the `DestGetJoined` method to retrieve the needed fields. See the documentation about that method, or read the `TestMany` procedure in `TTestSQLite3Engine._TSQLRestClientDB` method of the `SQLite3.pas` unit.

You may also take a look at the "Automatic JOIN query" new feature (in the 1.16 trunk): it will make your query just for you. See [this article](https://blog.synopse.info/?post/2011/12/06/Automatic-JOIN-query).

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of the tips! I'll review my code and I'm looking forward to the new features of the current version.